# Drupal 7 - How can I see EntityForm data as a page with custom URL Alias

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

First of all I want to say sorry if this question looks silly. I am only 19 days old as far as learning Drupal is concerned!

Can an EntityForm data be used as a content of the site with a custom URL alias? What I am trying is as follows:

I am creating a website where I want to list hotels according to place. To achieve the above I created three content types - Place, Amenities and Room Type. These fields are coming up fine when I created the EntityForm type named "Add Hotel Information" and of course the data also got saved fine in database when I added a hotel.

But I have no idea of how I can see this hotel information like a page with custom URL something like localhost/tours/hotels/grand-hotel-shimla. How I can do this?

Thank you for your help!

I have attached a screenshot of EntityForm.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page to display the data with the module **Views**
https://www.drupal.org/project/views

With that you can define a url for the page.

This might help you get started with using the module
https://www.drupal.org/node/1917630